# Let $v\in\Bbb F^n,U$ a subspace. Prove there is $m\in\Bbb N,b\in\Bbb F^m,A\in\Bbb M_{m\times n}(\Bbb F)$ s.t. $v+U=\{x\in\Bbb F^n\mid Ax=b\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $v \in \mathbb{F}{^n}$, $ U $ a subspace of $\mathbb{F}{^n}$. Prove that there is $ m \in \mathbb{N}, b\in \mathbb{F}{^m}, A \in \mathbb{M}{_m}_\times{_n}(\mathbb{F})$ such that:

$$
v + U = \{ x\in\mathbb{F}{^n}\mid Ax=b \}
$$

After thinking for like 15 minutes I come up with an idea to take the zero matrices to be A and the zero column to be the vector b. However I'm unsure if that is correct since I did not show the existence of a specific m value. Anyways, I'd like to know what's the strategy at solving questions like that (I mean, how should my "draft" page look like, should I try to define a b or a matrices first?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A = 0$ and $b = 0$ then the solutions to $Ax = b$ would be all of $\mathbb{F}^n$, not just $v + U$.

Try to solve the special case $v = 0$. Then use the observation that $x \in v + U$ iff $x - v \in U$.

This is in general a good approach, trying a special case (although it's not always obvious *which* special case) and then relating the general case with the special case.